# Memory Leak Calling Synchonous Method

Tags: memory-management

I have a small test function and I am getting memory allocation issue and memory warning after an hour of running. The problem is from the call to 
        NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error1];

Below is my code.
Any helps would be appreciated.

```
Here is my app stat after 1 hour running:  
Low: 712Kb, High 275.4 MB, Durarion 1 hour 26 min 

2015-01-31 14:38:11.811 testMem[5268:546116] Received memory warning.
2015-01-31 14:38:16.836 testMem[5268:546116] Received memory warning.
2015-01-31 14:38:24.573 testMem[5268:546116] Received memory warning.
2015-01-31 14:38:29.850 testMem[5268:546116] Received memory warning.
2015-01-31 14:38:34.779 testMem[5268:546116] Received memory warning.
2015-01-31 14:38:40.058 testMem[5268:546116] Received memory warning.
2015-01-31 14:38:44.922 testMem[5268:546116] Received memory warning.
```

MainView.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "global.h"


#import "ServiceSvc.h"
#import "ClsTickets.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSTimer* g_BACKUPTIMER;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    g_BACKUPTIMER = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.4 target:self selector:@selector(runBackupProcess) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)runBackupProcess
{
    if (stopTimer == 0)
    {
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(runtest) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    }
    else
    {

    }
}



- (void) runtest
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        @try
        {

            ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad *req2 = [[ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad alloc] init];
            req2.UnitDesc = @"Unit 6";
            req2.CustomerID = @"800014";
            req2.MachineID = nil;
            req2.UnitID = @"1";
            req2.GPSData = nil;

            ServiceSynchronous* synCrhous = [[ServiceSynchronous alloc] init];

            NSData* data = [synCrhous makeSynchrounousCall:req2];

            data = nil;
            req2 = nil;

        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
        }
        @finally
        {
        }
    } // end auto

}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

ServiceSvc.m

```
@implementation ServiceSynchronous
-(NSData*) makeSynchrounousCall:(ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad*) parameters
{
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error1 = nil;


    NSString *operationXMLString  = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:ServiceSvc=\"https://xxx/service.asmx\" xsl:version=\"1.0\"> <soap:Body> <ServiceSvc:DoAdminUnitIpad> <ServiceSvc:UnitID>1</ServiceSvc:UnitID> <ServiceSvc:UnitDesc>Unit 6</ServiceSvc:UnitDesc> <ServiceSvc:CustomerID>800014</ServiceSvc:CustomerID> </ServiceSvc:DoAdminUnitIpad> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                           [operationXMLString length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest * req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxx/service.asmx"]];
    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/webservice-name/method-name" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [req setHTTPBody:[operationXMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error1];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:req];

    if (error1 == nil)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

    operationXMLString = nil;
    req = nil;

    response = nil;
    return data;
}
@end


@implementation ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad
- (id)init
{
    if((self = [super init])) {
        UnitID = 0;
        UnitDesc = 0;
        CustomerID = 0;
        MachineID = 0;
        GPSData = 0;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *)nsPrefix
{
    return @"ServiceSvc";
}
- (xmlNodePtr)xmlNodeForDoc:(xmlDocPtr)doc elementName:(NSString *)elName elementNSPrefix:(NSString *)elNSPrefix
{

}
/* elements */
@synthesize UnitID;
@synthesize UnitDesc;
@synthesize CustomerID;
@synthesize MachineID;
@synthesize GPSData;
/* attributes */
- (NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    return attributes;
}
+ (ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad *)deserializeNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur
{
    ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad *newObject = [ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad new];

    [newObject deserializeAttributesFromNode:cur];
    [newObject deserializeElementsFromNode:cur];

    return newObject;
}
- (void)deserializeAttributesFromNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur
{
}
- (void)deserializeElementsFromNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur
{



}
@end
```

ServiceSvc.h

```
@interface ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad : NSObject {

/* elements */
    NSString * UnitID;
    NSString * UnitDesc;
    NSString * CustomerID;
    NSString * MachineID;
    NSString * GPSData;
/* attributes */
}
- (NSString *)nsPrefix;
- (xmlNodePtr)xmlNodeForDoc:(xmlDocPtr)doc elementName:(NSString *)elName elementNSPrefix:(NSString *)elNSPrefix;
- (void)addAttributesToNode:(xmlNodePtr)node;
- (void)addElementsToNode:(xmlNodePtr)node;
+ (ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad *)deserializeNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur;
- (void)deserializeAttributesFromNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur;
- (void)deserializeElementsFromNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur;
/* elements */
@property (retain) NSString * UnitID;
@property (retain) NSString * UnitDesc;
@property (retain) NSString * CustomerID;
@property (retain) NSString * MachineID;
@property (retain) NSString * GPSData;
/* attributes */
- (NSDictionary *)attributes;
@end

@interface ServiceSynchronous : NSObject {
}
- (NSData*) makeSynchrounousCall:(ServiceSvc_DoAdminUnitIpad*) parameters;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I came to the conclusion that Apple's NSURLConnection is the issue. The problem was reported back in 2008 and Apple had acknowledged it but now it is 2015 and the problem is still there. I have switched to asynchronous call and the memory allocation issue is still there, but smaller. Those geeks at Apple are a joke.